# Duplicate session creation & duplicate threads in AuthenticationProvider? Why?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stateless-session

So I have some Spring Boot Security code, and for some reason although my STATELESS angular app sends a single GET request. The Spring Security seems to get two requests and start processing them in the same milliseconds on two threads (then I end up getting a unique user constraint as it tries to add same user twice to the DB).

Is there something wrong with my spring security configuration where double-requests are happening? Spring Security should basically check ALL requests coming from stateless app for the X-AUTH-TOKEN.

```
http
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(new HeaderAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                //.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(request -> corsConfiguration), HeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error");
```

Basically HeaderAuthenticationProvider and HeaderAuthenticationFilter are used for checking X-AUTH-TOKEN.

```
2017-05-17 19:46:41.868  INFO 5 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [13,338] milliseconds.
2017-05-17 19:46:41.868  INFO 5 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [8,315] milliseconds.
2017-05-17 19:46:41.872  INFO 5 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] m.d.f.a.HeaderAuthenticationProvider     : Authenticate:: Authorization Token: bf6bbb6f5a850fb7b152b5e143534e5bd13a96abd3250d2
2017-05-17 19:46:41.872  INFO 5 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] m.d.f.a.HeaderAuthenticationProvider     : Authenticate:: Authorization Token: bf6bbb6f5a850fb7b152b5e143534e5bd13a96abd3250d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this issue. I had similar issue before and my issue was due to Spring started two `DelegateFilter` chains, one default and one customized. Instead, every filter was executed twice. From your log, it looks like you probably has similar issue. The way I solved it was to have my filter extends [`OncePerRequestFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html).